# Replace back arrow from navigation bar with hamburger

Tags: android, kotlin

My navigation at HomeFragment has hamburger icon which open navigation drawer.

[image]

When I open another fragment from navigation drawer I am getting back arrow that when clicked on will return me to HomeFragment.

[image]

[image]

How can I disable back arrow and replace it with existing hamburger that open navigation drawer?

```
private fun navigation(){
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.startingFragment)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigation_view, navController)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawer_layout)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable. ic_custom_drawer_icon);

Comment: I am sorry but I think this is not solution that I was searching for as I am not using any custom icons. I think there might be solution to use navController as working hamburger already exists.